# How to PROC PRINT only the sum of a column of data

Tags: sas

In SAS, you can use PROC PRINT to sum a column and display the sum:

```
proc print data = dataset.project_out;
    sum variable;
run;
```

How can I get this function to only print the sum line and not the rest of the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with `proc print`.  The closest you can come is the empty `var` statement:

```
proc print data=sashelp.class;
  var ;
  sum age;
run;
```

But `sum` adds the sum variable to the `var` list.

You can certainly accomplish this a number of other ways.

`PROC SQL` is the one I'd use:

```
proc sql;
  select sum(Age) from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

`PROC REPORT`, often called "pretty PROC PRINT", can do it also:

```
proc report data=sashelp.class;
  columns age;
  define age/analysis sum;
run;
```

`PROC TABULATE` can do it:

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.class;
  var age;
  tables age*sum;
run;
```

`PROC MEANS`:

```
proc means data=sashelp.class sum;
  var age;
run;
```

Etc., plenty of ways to do the same thing.