# Delete Total Line in SAS

Tags: sas, subtotal

Does anyone know of a way to remove the last blue total line?
[image]

This is the code I currently have:
title1 'Physical Exam Results By Patient';
footnote1;

```
proc print data=cert.transvisit1 noobs nosumlabel;
    id ID;
    var measure visitno1 visitno2 visitno3;
    sum visitno1 visitno2 visitno3;
    by ID;
run;
```

Comment: ?? You don't want totals then why did you ask for them by using the SUM statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to PROC PRINT only the sum of a column of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370651/how-to-proc-print-only-the-sum-of-a-column-of-data)

Comment: Remove the SUM statement.